# Countifs Function Help Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

Im putting in this formula in a Conditional Format in Excel.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6,"Black")>1
```

But when I do it, it highlights everything. I want it to check for duplicates in column a and after that check if column b contains the word "Black" and if it does, highlight the duplicate rows.

What it does currently:

[image]

What I want it to do:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6,"Black")>1`

Comment: Whoops, felt like I forgot something. But now it's highlighting the Cat and "White" as well. So anything with "Cat" in column A highlights.

Comment: That's strange, it should be specifically looking for "Black" since it's hardcoded.  Make sure you have cell A1 selected when you create the conditional format rule.

Comment: Ah, I see, the problem is that it's not specifying current row to check for "Black", so simply because there are two instances of Cat and Black for all rows of Cat, they get highlighted.  Need to add another condition: `=AND(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6,"Black")>1,$B1="Black")`

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050927/countifs-function-help-excel#comment87118573_50050927) to which OP responded *Yup, that did it! Thanks!*:

> `=AND(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6,"Black")>1,$B1="Black")`